# Не работает javac-комманда в bash скрипте

Tags: java, классы, bash, консоль, скрипт

не работает bash скрипт. Консоль выдает : line 5: javac: command not found

По отдельности файлы компилируются, то есть в них ошибок нет.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

javac -d . src/Main.java
java Main
javac -d . src/Code.java
java Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, в вашей системе не установлен JDK. Для debian-подобных систем вы можете установить JDK версии 17 следующей командой:

```bash
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk
```